# Android MediaPlayer Error 1021 - Create multi window instance fail

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

For some reason I cannot prevent my custom Player-App to get this error at random times during playback. Sometimes everything is running smooth for more than 24 hours before the error occurs, another time it will occur after a couple of minutes. 
It only occurs on Samsung T-805 and Samsung T-705 Tablets, all other devices I've tried (including a Samyung Galaxy Note Tab) can run for days without any errors.

```
OMX             setParam  sum(5120000) > max resolution(4177920)
OMXCodec        OmxCodec Create multi window instance fail  appPid : 14924
AwesomePlayer   CreateVideoDecoder(0x9e7475b0)::getMultiInstanceError - error: 2
MediaPlayer     error (1, -1021)
MediaPlayer     error (1,-1021)
```

My only guess is that it could have something to do with this:
[MediaCodec encoder using Surface crashes inconsistently on various devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581107/mediacodec-encoder-using-surface-crashes-inconsistently-on-various-devices)

Now my question: 
Since the error seems so random I don't really see the point of trying to prevent it from happening - I just want my player to recover from the error and resume playback. 
Any Ideas what I could try to get rid of the existing decoder-instance that is blocking my app? At the moment the only way to recover from this error is by restarting the tablet.

Comment: Unfortunately no. The error only occured on a special build of the Galaxy Tab S. After the next Android Update for the Tab S this never happened again.

Comment: any updates for this issue?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: No - other than updating to the current Android I did not